# Best Algorithm for solving USACO: Photoshoot - Python

Tags: python, combinatorics, complexity

I was trying to solve [this](http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=988) problem with Python 3.8. I couldn't find a way other than to brute-force calculate all the possible permutations then check which permutation was valid. The program works fine, but as it's `O(n!)` time complexity (I think) it takes extraordinarily long when the input has a length of, say, 1000.

My code:

```
from itertools import permutations as permute

fin = open("photo.in", "r")
fout = open("photo.out", "w+")

useless, line = fin.readlines()

nums = [int(i) for i in line.split(" ")]

def main(nums):
    foo = [i+1 for i in range(len(nums)+1)]
    bar = permute(foo)
    
    for permutation in bar:
      boo = False
      for i in range(1, len(permutation)):
          if permutation[i]+permutation[i-1] != nums[i-1]:
              boo = False
              break
          else:
            boo = True
      
      if boo:
          return permutation

final = " ".join([str(i) for i in main(nums)])
fout.write(final)

fin.close()
fout.close()
```

I'm not sure how to optimize this code. Should I create my own permutation generator function and then check along the way instead of getting the whole thing at once? Or is there an algorithm that I'm not seeing?

A short problem description:
Given a list *N* of length *n* integers, find a permutation of the numbers 1 through *n*+1 in which every element of the permutation plus the next one is equal to the corresponding number of *N*.

Edit: The generator approach did not work.

Comment: _Or is there an algorithm that I'm not seeing?_ - Yes there is.

Comment: @vnp Can you give me a hint as to what I'm missing?

Comment: you have \$ n \$ equations and \$ n \$ variables (the last equation being \$ a_1 + a_2 + \cdots = \dfrac{n (n+1)}{2} \$).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Mathematical approach

Let us assume the following notation:

$$ \mathbb{B} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} b_i = b_1 + b_2 + \cdots + b_{n-1} $$

As mentioned earlier in comments, you have set of interdependent equations as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
b_1 &= a_1 + a_2 \\
b_2 &= a_2 + a_3 \\
b_3 &= a_3 + a_4 \\
\vdots \\
b_{n - 1} &= a_{n - 1} + a_n \\
\end{align}
$$

The above is \$ n - 1 \$ sets of equations, and the last equation you can derive from those is:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} b_i &= \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i + \sum_{j = 2}^{n - 1} a_j \\
\implies \mathbb{B} + (a_1 + a_n) &= 2 \times \left( \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_i 
\right) \\
\implies a_1 + a_n &= 2 \times \left( \dfrac{n (n + 1)}{2} \right) - \mathbb{B} \\
&= \left( n \cdot (n + 1) \right) - \mathbb{B} \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

---

Now, let's see what happens if we try the summation with a slight variation:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} \left[ (-1)^{i + 1} \cdot b_i \right] &= b_1 - b_2 + b_3 - \cdots \cdots (-1)^{n - 2} b_{n - 1} \\
&= (a_1 + a_2) - (a_2 + a_3) + (a_3 + a_4) - \cdots \cdots + (-1)^n (a_{n - 1} + a_n) \\
&= a_1 + (-1)^{n} a_n \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Now, there would be 2 cases; 1 is fairly straight to solve:

#### Case 1: \$ n \$ is odd

The equation 2 becomes: $$ a_1 - a_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} \left[ (-1)^{i + 1} \cdot b_i \right] $$

giving you the direct result (adding equation to above):

$$
a_1 = \dfrac{1}{2} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} \left[ (-1)^{i + 1} \cdot b_i \right] + n^2 + n - \mathbb{B} \right)
$$

#### Case 2: \$ n \$ is even

This gives you the same result as equation 1, therefore the replacement operation from [SylvainD's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/250067/12240) comes into play. I'll leave this for the programming specific solution.

---

### Program/code review

1. Use the names of variables which are closer to words used in problem statement. This makes it easier to go through code and question at the same time.
2. The `photo.in` serves no purpose once it has been read, use a contextual open for this:

   ```
   with open("photo.in", "r") as file_in:
       num_cows = int(file_in.readline())
       summations = map(int, file_in.readline().split(" "))
   ```
3. Same as above, the `photo.out` serves no purpose until you want to write:

   ```
   with open("photo.out", "w+") as file_out:
       file_out.write(" ".join(output_string))
   ```

Comment: oh man, thanks a ton for the file reading suggestion at the end bro! you rock!

Answer (score 4):

**No need to compute permutations**

As you are provided all the `b1,b2,…,bN−1` values, the problem boils down to finding the first value `a1` and everything can be computed from there. In particular, you have only `N` different values to try. We can try see them like this:

```
n = 5
b_array = [4, 6, 7, 6]
for a in range(1, n+1):
    a_array = [a]
    for b in b_array:
        a = b - a
        a_array.append(a)
    print(a_array)
```

which gives

```
[1, 3, 3, 4, 2] # Duplicate 3
[2, 2, 4, 3, 3] # Duplicate 2
[3, 1, 5, 2, 4] # Looks good
[4, 0, 6, 1, 5] # 6 is out of range
[5, -1, 7, 0, 6] # -1, 7, 6, 0 are out of range
```

Because we go with increasing values of `a1`, the first candidate that does match is the expected solution (the "lexicographically minimum").

Thus, you could just try to get rid of the impossible solution and you'll find the correct one:

```
def get_solution(n, b_array):
    for a in range(1, n+1):
        a_array = [a]
        for b in b_array:
            a = b -a
            if 0 < a <= n and a not in a_array: # To be performed with a set for O(1) check
                a_array.append(a)
            else:
                break
        else: # No break
            return a_array

n = 5
b_array = [4, 6, 7, 6]
print(get_solution(n, b_array))
```

This solution is O(n*n): n attempts (or maybe n/2 on average) which iterate over n elements (or maybe n/2 on average).

It would be nice to find an O(n) solution (which is the best expectable solution).

**Mathematical observations**

We have: `bi = ai + ai+1` which means `ai+1 = bi - ai` which is the property we've used previously.
From there, we can also compute: `ai+2 = bi+1 - ai+1 = bi+1 - bi + ai`.
It doesn't look very interesting at first but it means that when if you try to increase/decrease `ai` from a fixed value, the value `ai+2` will vary accordingly (and so will the value of `ai+4`, `ai+6`, etc).

This can be observed in the options we generated previously:

```
[1,  3, 3, 4, 2] # Duplicate 3
[2,  2, 4, 3, 3] # Duplicate 2
[3,  1, 5, 2, 4] # Looks good
[4,  0, 6, 1, 5] # 6 is out of range
[5, -1, 7, 0, 6] # -1, 7, 6, 0 are out of range
 ^______^_________always +2 from column 1 to 3
 ^____________^___always +1 from column 1 to 5
     ^_____^______always +1 from column 2 to 4
```

Note: this property hold when we take every other column but not when we take 2 consecutives values because `ai+2 - ai = bi+1 - bi` is a fixed value (which is convenient) while `ai+1 - a1 =  bi - 2*ai` depends on the value of `ai`.

How could this help us ?

Well, in your case, we can see that a3 = a1 + 2 which tells us straightaway that a1 can't be 4 or above. With a bigger list, this would provide us a smaller range to check for `a1` (both from the starting limit and the ending limit).

Similarly, we can get stronger constraints on `a2`.

---

**My final version of the code**

In case it can be useful, here is my implementation. It doesn't use all the excellent ideas from hjpotter92's answers:

```
# https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250061/efficient-permutation-checking-for-usaco-photoshoot-python
# http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=988
import random

def generate_b_array(a_array):
    """Generate 'b' array from the 'a' array."""
    return [previous + current for previous, current in zip(a_array, a_array[1:])]


def generate_problem(n):
    """Generate a problem of size n."""
    # TODO: It is a bit trickier than this, we may generate solutions which
    # are not the lexicographical minimum:
    # For instance, both [4, 3, 2, 1] and [3, 4, 1, 2] lead to b being [7, 5, 3]
    # But only the second one is an acceptable solution
    # This issue gets less and less common as n increases.
    a = list(range(1, n+1))
    random.shuffle(a)
    return a, generate_b_array(a)


def get_solution_naive(b_array):
    """This is the most straight-forward solution: generate and check."""
    n = len(b_array) + 1
    expected_set = set(range(1, n+1))
    for a in range(1, n+1):
        a_array = [a]
        for b in b_array:
            a = b -a
            a_array.append(a)
        if set(a_array) == expected_set:
            return a_array


def get_solution_naive_early_stop(b_array):
    """Smarter (?) solution: trying to stop when generated data is not valid."""
    n = len(b_array) + 1
    for a in range(1, n+1):
        a_array = [a]
        for b in b_array:
            a = b -a
            if 0 < a <= n and a not in a_array:
                a_array.append(a)
            else:
                break
        else: # No break
            return a_array


def get_solution_naive_early_stop_set(b_array):
    """Smarter (?) solution: trying to stop when generated data is not valid, using the most appropriate data structure."""
    n = len(b_array) + 1
    for a in range(1, n+1):
        a_array = [a]
        a_set = set(a_array)
        for b in b_array:
            a = b -a
            if 0 < a <= n and a not in a_set:
                a_array.append(a)
                a_set.add(a)
            else:
                break
        else: # No break
            return a_array


def get_solution(b_array):
    """Optimised solution: rely on mathematical observation to limit the number of values checked."""
    n = len(b_array) + 1

    # Use properties on alternate indices to restrict values to look for for a1
    b_diff = [current - previous for previous, current in zip(b_array, b_array[1:])]

    delta_from_a1 = [0]
    for delta in b_diff[::2]:
        delta_from_a1.append(delta + delta_from_a1[-1])
    min_delta_a1, max_delta_a1 = min(delta_from_a1), max(delta_from_a1)
    delta_from_a2 = [0]
    for delta in b_diff[1::2]:
        delta_from_a2.append(delta + delta_from_a2[-1])
    min_delta_a2, max_delta_a2 = min(delta_from_a2), max(delta_from_a2)

    # We want: 0 < a_n <= N for all n
    # With a_n = a_1 + delta_n, we want: -delta_n < a_1 <= N - delta_n for all n
    # In particular:
    #  -min(delta) < a_1 <= N - max(delta)
    a1_min1 = 1 - min_delta_a1
    a1_max1 = n - max_delta_a1

    # We want: 0 < a_n <= N for all n
    # With a_n = a_2 + delta_n and a2 = b1 - a1, we want:
    #  0 < b_1 - a_1 + delta_n <= N for all n
    #  - delta_n - b_1 < - a_1 <= N - delta_n - b_1
    #  delta_n + b_1 > a_1 >= delta_n + b_1 - N
    # In particular :
    #  max(delta) + b-1 - N <= a_1 < min(delta) + b_1 
    a1_min2 = max_delta_a2 + b_array[0] - n
    a1_max2 = min_delta_a2 + b_array[0] - 1

    a1_min = max(1, a1_min1, a1_min2)
    a1_max = min(n, a1_max1, a1_max2)
    # print("min", a1_min, 1, a1_min1, a1_min2)
    # print("max", a1_max, n, a1_max1, a1_max2)

    expected_set = set(range(1, n+1))
    for a in range(a1_min, a1_max+1):
        a_array = [a]
        for b in b_array:
            a = b -a
            a_array.append(a)
        if set(a_array) == expected_set:
            return a_array



def check_solution(a, b):
    """Test all implementations on a given problem."""
    # TODO: Some performance benchmarking could be added here.
    a1 = get_solution_naive(b)
    a2 = get_solution_naive_early_stop(b)
    a3 = get_solution_naive_early_stop_set(b)
    a4 = get_solution(b)
    if a1 != a:
        print("a1", a, a1, b)
    if a2 != a:
        print("a2", a, a2, b)
    if a3 != a:
        print("a3", a, a3, b)
    if a4 != a:
        print("a4", a, a3, b)


def perform_tests():
    """Perform tests (hardcoded & randomly generated)."""
    a, b = [3, 1, 5, 2, 4], [4, 6, 7, 6]
    check_solution(a, b)

    a, b = [6, 3, 10, 4, 2, 1, 8, 7, 5, 9], [9, 13, 14, 6, 3, 9, 15, 12, 14]
    check_solution(a, b)

    a, b = [12, 5, 9, 6, 14, 10, 15, 13, 2, 7, 1, 8, 19, 11, 16, 20, 4, 18, 17, 3], [17, 14, 15, 20, 24, 25, 28, 15, 9, 8, 9, 27, 30, 27, 36, 24, 22, 35, 20]
    check_solution(a, b)

    # This case leads to more iterations than most other cases
    a = [137, 187, 70, 179, 198, 106, 156, 10, 144, 105, 196, 171, 89, 164, 186, 41, 165, 55, 114, 138, 101, 8, 75, 185, 174, 81, 158, 126, 181, 30, 178, 85, 180, 76, 28, 56, 62, 119, 193, 45, 94, 109, 172, 169, 149, 79, 189, 100, 125, 131, 57, 32, 139, 14, 27, 152, 47, 15, 147, 95, 39, 112, 118, 151, 38, 26, 175, 11, 200, 1, 161, 120, 63, 115, 12, 60, 129, 80, 7, 33, 192, 166, 123, 13, 23, 84, 116, 6, 163, 16, 52, 5, 18, 71, 154, 78, 69, 3, 49, 121, 199, 159, 72, 86, 36, 54, 92, 97, 35, 34, 150, 173, 168, 130, 190, 141, 99, 17, 87, 134, 20, 155, 111, 153, 170, 102, 31, 135, 9, 194, 50, 4, 128, 140, 143, 184, 40, 110, 191, 98, 44, 195, 58, 24, 65, 74, 64, 22, 197, 188, 113, 142, 136, 107, 103, 83, 19, 145, 53, 68, 167, 59, 177, 21, 182, 2, 122, 176, 117, 51, 48, 67, 183, 61, 82, 42, 124, 37, 93, 162, 73, 148, 127, 66, 146, 29, 91, 108, 160, 157, 104, 25, 132, 43, 96, 88, 46, 77, 133, 90]
    b = [324, 257, 249, 377, 304, 262, 166, 154, 249, 301, 367, 260, 253, 350, 227, 206, 220, 169, 252, 239, 109, 83, 260, 359, 255, 239, 284, 307, 211, 208, 263, 265, 256, 104, 84, 118, 181, 312, 238, 139, 203, 281, 341, 318, 228, 268, 289, 225, 256, 188, 89, 171, 153, 41, 179, 199, 62, 162, 242, 134, 151, 230, 269, 189, 64, 201, 186, 211, 201, 162, 281, 183, 178, 127, 72, 189, 209, 87, 40, 225, 358, 289, 136, 36, 107, 200, 122, 169, 179, 68, 57, 23, 89, 225, 232, 147, 72, 52, 170, 320, 358, 231, 158, 122, 90, 146, 189, 132, 69, 184, 323, 341, 298, 320, 331, 240, 116, 104, 221, 154, 175, 266, 264, 323, 272, 133, 166, 144, 203, 244, 54, 132, 268, 283, 327, 224, 150, 301, 289, 142, 239, 253, 82, 89, 139, 138, 86, 219, 385, 301, 255, 278, 243, 210, 186, 102, 164, 198, 121, 235, 226, 236, 198, 203, 184, 124, 298, 293, 168, 99, 115, 250, 244, 143, 124, 166, 161, 130, 255, 235, 221, 275, 193, 212, 175, 120, 199, 268, 317, 261, 129, 157, 175, 139, 184, 134, 123, 210, 223]
    check_solution(a, b)

    lengths = [3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 100, 200, 500]
    lengths = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 20, 100, 200, 500]
    for i in lengths:
        a, b = generate_problem(i)
        check_solution(a, b)

perform_tests()
```

---

The code review itself

Here are a few comments which could help you:

- write functions
- write tests for your functions: this is particularly easy here for 2 reasons:
  * you are provided a valid test case
  * new test cases are fairly easy to generate

Writing functions will help you to write easier to maintain code. Also, for the algorithmic challenges, it will help you to focus on the algorithm itself instead of dealing with input/output. Also, it helps to test various implementations, to test them, to compare them (both in correctness and in performances)

Comment: I'm not convinced your solution is O(n^2). It rather looks like O(n^3) to me. Or does `0 < a <= n and a not in a_array` average O(1) somehow?

Comment: Oh, I meant to perform this with a set but forgot. I'll try to fix this, thanks for the comment.

Comment: We can also compute the sum of the first and last a-value, as every a-value gets into b twice, except those two. I don't see how to take advantage of it, though. And I suspect O(n) isn't possible or at least hard to achieve, since otherwise I'd expect a limit higher than 1000.

Comment: Well, it turns out that I was thinking about this problem in the wrong way. Thank you so much bro!

Comment: @superbrain The implementation I've provided is probably very close to O(n). The pre-computation ensures that the loop actually goes through a small number of iterations (almost always 1) but I can't prove it.

Comment: Your checks like `a1 != a` aren't right. I tried replacing your `random.shuffle(a)` with the non-random shuffle `a[1::2], a[::2] = a[:n//2], a[n//2:][::-1]` and then those checks failed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'll give it a try!

Comment: @superbrain After a check, it actually corresponds to the issue hilighted in the comment of the `generate_problem` function. I guess this could get fixed somehow but it was good enough for most usages.